# magento1: what is use of catalog_product_index_eav table

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I have created product attribute with the dropdown in Magento.

Product attribute backend type is int and attribute is filterable with results. but then find the values of that attribute in the **catalog_product_entity_int** table but it's not showing. but when I am finding in the **catalog_product_index_eav** table it's showing. I am confused what is the use of catalog_product_index_eav table and why it's showing value in that table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Attributes are store into "**eav_attribute**" table in magento.

IF you open this table , you can see field name **attribute_code** && **attribute_id** are there where attribute_id is primary key

Now this table is joined with other table depend on attribute type like select , int , varchar etc.

Means IF attribute input type is int, than it will join with **catalog_product_entity_int** table.
**catalog_product_index_eav** used for product attribute indexing data store.
IF you truncate this table & running indexer of magento, this table data will generate.